# Github desktop: where is "add"?

Tags: git, github

I use the Github Desktop for Windows, but I can't find "git add", it only has "commit to xxx", and it seems that its "commit" equals "git add + git commit" in git bash. But I can't find answer from its document, can anyone tell me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to try and shed some light on your problem. You mentioned that:

(#1) I can't find "git add"
(#2) it only has "commit to xxx", and it seems that its "commit" equals "git add + git commit" in git bash

Your second statement is correct. The commit button is sort of the same as "git add + git commit" in git bash.

However...

Once you have clicked on commit and the indicator shows that the processing of the commit is complete, you will want to click on "Sync" at the top right corner, as this is what actually syncs the repository on Github with the one on your local device.

One more thing...

There is an "add" button that you can click but it refers to adding a new repository to your Github project repository list that is found on the left hand side of the bash screen. I am including a screenshot of my Github Bash screen in order to provide you with a reference.

[image]

You will notice that there is a "+" sign at the top left corner. If you click on that you will get a menu that gives the choices of "add", "create", or "clone". That of course has NOTHING to do with pushing changes in code to the remote Github repository. That section is just used to add a repository from the remote repositories to your local device.

I hope that helps ZK!

Comment: Thanks! Your answer completely solve my problem, and also thanks for your snapshot. And in the latest beta version which i'm using, 'sync' button has been replaced by 'Push/Publish/Fetch'. I like this change because I think it should respect the principle of git ^=^ .